# socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known docker-compose + rabbitmq + pika (Python)

Tags: python, docker-compose, rabbitmq, docker-network, pika

I have docker container with rabbitmq, it has an address: 192.168.220.10, domain in my local etc/hosts: rabbitmq

So, Im trying to use pika (python) from another container with fastapi app, it has an address: 192.168.220.5.

Of course, all containers have a network:
`net: driver: bridge ipam: config: - subnet: 192.168.220.0/24`

Below rabbitmq container code from docker-compose.yml

```
rabbitmq:
  container_name: rabbitmq
  image: rabbitmq:3-management-alpine
  restart: always
  ports:
    - "5672:5672"
    - "15672:15672"
  environment:
    RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: rabbitmq
    RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS: 27474129
  networks:
    net:
      ipv4_address: 192.168.220.10
```

So theres a problem at the bottom

```
credentials = pika.PlainCredentials('rabbitmq', '27474129')
conn_params = pika.ConnectionParameters(host="http://rabbitmq", port=5672)
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(conn_params)
channel = connection.channel()
```

Im getting an error: socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

I`ve tried:
Use ports: 15672 and 5672.
Use host: "http://192.168.220.10

Answer (score 0):

```
parameters = pika.URLParameters('amqp://rabbitmq:27474129@rabbitmq:5672/%2F')
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)
```